# Git - Merge branch with other branch - specific files only (multiple files)

Tags: git, syntax, git-merge, git-checkout

In `git`, can we checkout and merge *specific files only; by filtering them*? (From one branch to another branch)

If I have two branches:

```
   BranchMergeInto
   BranchMergeFrom
```

I am aware that you can do the following to add singular files into a different branch.

```
   git checkout BranchMergeInto
   git checkout BranchMergeFrom -- FileToInsertIntoOtherBranch.file
```

> I want to **filter** the files I want to add into the *destination branch*.

For instance *(doesn't work)* I would like to do something like this:

```
   git checkout BranchMergeInto
   git checkout BranchMergeFrom -- *.file
```

This however does not nothing..

Thanks!

Comment: Perfect thanks, I had to update my `git version` because it did not have `git restore`. Solution : `git restore --source BranchName '*.ext'`

Comment: For everyone else seeing this, **make sure to use `'` characters around filter, without them ie `git restore --source BranchName *.ext` does not work!